# Is it worth creating and using an index on the sorted table?

Tags: sql, database, indexing

I understand that we create indexes in order to facilitate look-ups and retrieval of data from the disk especially that data is located in many blocks. Let us suppose that we have a table stored in our database and that table is already sorted based on some criteria. Is it worth it to create an index on that table so that the retrieval is even more faster?

Comment: Which database software are you talking about?  SQL Server? Oracle? Something else?

Answer (score 1):

I will simplify a bit, but it should still get the point across. A table can only be physically sorted according to one key, called the clustered index, usually the same as the primary key. If you need to do lookups on columns other than those contained the clustered index, the data will *not* be sorted and there is the potential for the need for a full table scan on the clustered index. If your table is large enough and you do a lot of queries that involve columns other than the clustered index, then you will need to create additional indexes on the other columns.

As always, actually measure the results to see if it matters and also make sure to look at execution plans to see if it makes a difference. In some cases, it doesn't matter.

Finally, indexes will slow down insert and update operations, as the indexes will need to be updated in addition to the regular table data. You will thus need to consider the types of operations that frequently happen on your table. If inserts are infrequent, but reads are frequent, then indexes will help. If you're mostly inserting data and rarely reading it, don't bother with the indexes.

Comment: There is ta least one product (TokuDB) that allows more than one clustering index.

Comment: Terminology... TokuDB makes a "copy" of the original table for each "clustered index". I.e. it's not the same physical table sorted differently.